# React + Babel: How can I load a CSS file for a shared component library?

Tags: css, reactjs, babeljs

I'm currently trying to build a shared component library that I can use across my different projects.

This is my index.js file:

```
import Avatar from "./components/Avatar";
import Heading1 from "./components/Heading1";

import styles from "./global.css";

export { Avatar, Heading1 };
```

The    reason I am loading `global.css` is because I want to use a custom font.

When I run `babel src -d build`, it seems to skip my CSS file:

```
myapp-ui edmund/theming % npm run build

> @myapp/ui@0.1.0 build /Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/myapp/myapp-ui
> babel src -d build

src/components/Avatar.js -> build/components/Avatar.js
src/components/Heading1.js -> build/components/Heading1.js
src/index.js -> build/index.js
src/stories/Avatar.stories.js -> build/stories/Avatar.stories.js
src/stories/Headling1.stories.js -> build/stories/Headling1.stories.js
src/theme.js -> build/theme.js
```

When I go into one of my apps and try to load this shared component library, it also throws an error about a missing CSS file:

```
Failed to compile.

../myapp-ui/build/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './global.css' in '/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/myapp/myapp-ui/build'
```

How would I load a CSS or custom font for a shared component library?

Comment: Have you tried just importing the file? ```import "./global.css";```

Comment: Yeh. That was the first thing I did actually

Comment: You just need to add [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) to webpack

Comment: @ArtemBalamutyuk you were right. i switched from using just babel to webpack and css loader